# Is it possible to find out the lat and long of an area(not added in the google map) without using any maps api?

Tags: php, html, google-maps, maps, latitude-longitude

Is it possible to find out the lat and long of an area(not added in the google map) without using maps api? 
If Yes, how? 
If No, why?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad in its current form. Please give concrete details of what you a trying to achieve, for example, how do you define the area you intend to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is other API than gmap API that can be used to find lat lng of a place :

https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/requests-pf.html

http://www.mapquestapi.com/

I can't tell you if they're good only been using gmap API

Comment: can I achieve it without using any of the APIs?

Comment: You will need data stored to find the lat/lng of a place, if you need only a few place you can use an api to get the data and then store it on your server to have access to it without depending on any API

Comment: Also i've found another one that can be helpful

Comment: No issues regarding your triple comment :-P

Comment: But could you please explain me a bit about your first comment!?

Comment: What i was saying is if you don't want to use an api, you can get the lat/lng of the places you need with something like http://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html or any api mentionned and you store the lat/lng in your own database so you won't need to use any api to find it again (this is in case you need lat/lng of a few places)

Comment: Right (y)   Thanks